# Aggregations on PyElasticSearch (pyes)

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I wish to calculate value-count aggregations on some indexed product data, but I seem to be getting some parameters in the `ValueCountAgg` constructor wrong.

An example of such indexed data is as follows -:

```
{
  "_index": "test-index",
  "_type": "product_product",
  "_id": "1",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "code": "SomeProductCode1",
    "list_price": 10,
    "description": null,
    "displayed_on_eshop": "true",
    "active": "true",
    "tree_nodes": [],
    "id": 1,
    "category": {},
    "name": "This is Product",
    "price_lists": [
      {
        "price": 10,
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "price": 10,
        "id": 2
      }
    ],
    "attributes": {
      "color": "blue",
      "attrib": "something",
      "size": "L"
    },
    "type": "goods"
  }
}
```

I'm calculating aggregations as follows -:

```
for attribute in filterable_attributes:
    count = ValueCountAgg(
        name='count_'+attribute, field='attributes.'+attribute
    )
    query.agg.add(count)
```

where `query` is a `~pyes.query.Query` object wrapped inside a `~pyes.query.Search` object. `filterable_attributes` is a list of attribute names, such as color and size.

I have tried setting `field=attribute` as well, but it seems to make no difference. The resultset that I obtain on conducting the search has the following as its `aggs` attribute -:

```
{'count_size': {'value': 0}, 'count_color': {'value': 0}}
```

where `size` and `color` are indexed inside the `attributes` dictionary as shown above. These are evidently wrong results, and I think it is because I am not setting `field` properly.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've found where I was going wrong.

According to [Scoping Aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scoping_aggregations.html), the scope of an aggregation is by default associated with its query. My query was returning zero results, and I had to modify the search phrase for the same.

I got the required results after that, and aggregations are coming out right.

```
{'count_size': {'value': 3}, 'count_color': {'value': 3}}
```